# Unable to install/use app using android.hardware.usb

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, usb, dji-sdk, lineageos

I have a build of LineageOs 16 running on a Raspberry Pi 4 where I am trying to develop applications using the DJI Mobile SDK for Android.

The SDK requires the manifest line

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory"
    android:required="true" />
```

In order to connect over USB  to the remote controller/drone. However, when I install the app, I get the following error:

```
adb: failed to install ~/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.dji.FPVDemo-r4xQI7EHLLS97SoutrNC3A==: Package com.dji.FPVDemo requires unavailable shared library android.hardware.usb; failing!
```

I removed the Manifest line, but then there is no USB connection; we see

```
E DJIUsbAccessoryReceiver: android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE: no connected
```

This is where I am stuck.